# df looping through df and creating new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, while-loop

Im trying to write a loop through code whereby 1 line(row) in df1 multiplies through every row in  df2 and then the next row in df1 does the same thing until the end then it breaks. Cant seem to get the actual code form together. Tried a for loop with iterrows but didnt get what i was looking for.

df1
|A |B | C| [10,5,4] [5,10,5] [20,10,8] [10 10 10]....

df2

|A |B | C| [1,.9,.8] [.95,.75,.6] [.9,.85,.65] ...

Output would look like
column D

row 1 (10*1)+(5*.9)+(4*.8)= 17.7

row 2 (10*.95)+(5*.75)+(4*(.6)=15.65

......................

row 4 (5*1) +(10*.9) +(5*.8)=

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your problem? Also, remember to format your code properly! [This post will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
result = []

for i, row in df1.iterrows():
  for j, row2 in df2.iterrows():
    result.append(sum(row*row2))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[17.7, 15.65, 15.85, 18.0, 15.25, 16.25, 35.4, 31.3, 31.7, 27.0, 23.0, 24.0]
```

The only point is that the size of the result can not be used for a column in one of the two dataframes because the size differs. It's up to you to create a new dataframe or to keep the result in a list depending on what you need to do with that